# How to use IS_DATE function of Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column 'POSTING_DATE' in snowflake table as VARCHAR data type

I have used the is_date function as below to check whether the value in the column is a date or not.

IS_DATE(TO_VARIANT(POSTING_DATE))

The to_variant conversion is used inside, is due to the fact that the function is_date supports only variant data type as argument.

The output is not correct

[image]

Can somebody please help me in getting the correct syntax of is_date function  in snowflake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate if a VARCHAR text is a valid date you coul use [TRY_TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html) with explicit format:

```
SELECT POSTING_DATE, 
       TRY_TO_DATE(POSTING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NOT NULL AS Is_valid_non_null_date
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 1):

As POSTING_DATE is a string, you'd be better off using TRY_TO_DATE

Answer (score 0):

IS_DATE is used for semi structured data func's and takes variant as input. As you are checking on varchar column holding date  , TO_DATE() and DATE() works well for your conversion.

**Examples:**

```
  select to_date(POSTING_DATE,'AUTO'), date(POSTING_DATE, 'AUTO');
      or
  select to_date(POSTING_DATE,<FORMAT>), date(POSTING_DATE, <FORMAT>);
```